# function calling itself

Tags: php, oop

again with another problem.

```
public function __construct() {
    $_GET = $this->clean($_GET);
    $_POST = $this->clean($_POST);
    ...

}

public function clean($data) {
    if (is_array($data)) {
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            unset($data[$key]);

            $data[$this->clean($key)] = $this->clean($value);
        }
    } else { 
        $data = htmlspecialchars($data, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
    }

    return $data;
}
```

i dont understand why `$data[$this->clean($key)] = $this->clean($value);` is calling its own function. what is the point of doing this? the advantages

thanks,
daniel

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a technique called recursion. This particular function descends into the structure until it is dealing with very simple data and sanitizes it all.

Given this:

```
$arr = array (
   '<foo' => array(
       'bat' => 'OMGWTFBBQ!!><!?!'
   ),
   'bar' => 'baz'
);
```

It would start:

1. is arr an array?

   1. is `<foo` an array? (no)

      - `<foo` becomes `&lt;foo`
      - `&lt;foo` used as a key
   2. is the value of `<foo` an array? (yes)

      1. Is bat an array? (no)

         - `bat` remains as is (still has htmlspecialchars called, but it does not change anything))
      2. Is `'OMGWTFBBQ!!><!?!'` an array (no)?

         - `'OMGWTFBBQ!!><!?!'` is converted to `'OMGWTFBBQ!!&gt;&lt;!?!'`
         - `'OMGWTFBBQ!!&gt;&lt;!?!'` is used for the value for bat.
   3. Is 'bar' an array? (no)

      1. `bar` returned as is (like bat above)
      2. Is baz an array? (no)

         - `baz` returned as is.

You can think of it this way

```
$arr = array (
   '<foo' => array(
       'bat' => 'OMGWTFBBQ!!><!?!'
   ),
   'bar' => 'baz'
);

///////////////////////////////////////////
array (
   clean('<foo') => array(
       'bat' => 'OMGWTFBBQ!!><!?!'
   ),
   'bar' => 'baz'
);

///////////////////////////////////////////
array (
   '&lt;foo' => clean( array(
       'bat' => 'OMGWTFBBQ!!><!?!'
   )),
   'bar' => 'baz'
);

///////////////////////////////////////////
array (
   '&lt;foo' => array(
       clean( 'bat' ) => 'OMGWTFBBQ!!><!?!'
   )),
   'bar' => 'baz'
);

///////////////////////////////////////////
array (
   '&lt;foo' => array(
       'bat' => clean( 'OMGWTFBBQ!!><!?!' )
   )),
   'bar' => 'baz'
);

///////////////////////////////////////////
array (
   '&lt;foo' => array(
       'bat' => 'OMGWTFBBQ!!&gt;&lt;!?!'
   )),
  clean( 'bar' ) => 'baz'
);
///////////////////////////////////////////
array (
   '&lt;foo' => array(
       'bat' => 'OMGWTFBBQ!!&gt;&lt;!?!'
   )),
  'bar' => clean( 'baz' )
);
///////////////////////////////////////////
return array (
   '&lt;foo' => array(
       'bat' => 'OMGWTFBBQ!!&gt;&lt;!?!'
   )),
  'bar' => 'baz'
);
```

Comment: ok.. kinda understand. can you explain this: so when '<foo' enters $data[$this->clean($key)] and the function is called again it skips the for loop, enters the else then $data is returned. so how is it iterated?  can you explain in sudo code the process of step 1.1

Comment: I added a more explicit step-by-step of how the data looks. Hopefully that will be enough.

Answer (score 3):

clean function uses `htmlspecialchars` to clean html chars from string. But if `$data` is an array it calls itself for cleaning all of its keys and values. This is why clean is recursive.

The advantage of this approach is clean function works for string and array transparently.

Answer (score 0):

It's called [recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29).

In your example the $_GET and $_POST arrays may contain elements which are also arrays which themselves can contain arrays (ad infinitum). So you don't know how many sub-arrays you will have to clean up.

To solve this problem the function `clean` is written in a manner that it calls itself when it occurs a "sub array" while cleaning the current array. It's like a loop just for nested data structures.